# code explatation in java

Tags: java, inheritance, syntax

I came across a piece of code. What does this line of code actually mean ? `public class Queue<E extends Element>{` I understand that E can be any object but why add `extends Element`. Element is a separate class that contains 2 variables + getters and setters. What are the advantages / disadvantages of using that syntax ?

Comment: It restricts the `Queue` to only begin able to contain `Object`s that extend from `Element`.  It basically means, that at the very least, this `Queue` will only contain instances of `Element` (or Objects that extend from it)...You should take a look at [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more details ;)

Comment: Just go through - [Generics FAQs - Type Parameter Bounds](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Bounds).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you can create a concrete instance of `Queue<E>` only if `E` extends `Element`. So for instance, this declaration would fail:

```
Queue<String> q; // Invalid
```

...because `String` doesn't extend `Element`.

It's useful because within the implementation of `Queue<E>`, you (and the compiler) know `E` has the properties and methods of `Element`, and so you can use them. If the declaration were just `public class Queue<E>{`, then if you tried to use `Element` properties or methods of the `E`-typed arguments and members, the compiler would complain because those properties/methods don't exist on `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

The type `E` that the generic `Queue` class is instantiated with must inherit from `Element`.

The code in the `Queue` class depends on (has calls to) the `Element` class methods.